# How to install NCalc in Visual Basic .NET project?

Tags: vb.net, expression, ncalc

I'm making a programme which has to evaluate function expressions like f(x) = x^2+6x-9, using Visual Basic (.NET).

I suppose the only way I can do this is by using NCalc, so I downloaded it and I can see that it is installed under 'Project > Manage NuGet Packages'. But I just don't have any idea what to do next. Do I have to declare something in my project before it can be used? Because now this still gives an error:

```
Dim e As Expression
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add an imports to the top of your file:

```
Imports Ncalc
```

Then you can use it as you described:

```
Dim x As New Expression("x^2+6*x-9")
x.Parameters.Add("x", "4")
Dim result = x.Evaluate
MessageBox.Show(result)
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. A green line appears under 'Ncalc', saying that it can't be found. What should I do?

Comment: Look at your references in your project and see if NCalc is there.

Comment: It wasn't there. Now that I added NCalc, it works. Thank you for your help!